# Register Dynamically Loaded Custom ASP Control's Script to DOM

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I load my ascx control during a **postback** (a dropdown change event):

Parent C#:

```
private void ddlChange() 
{
    MyControl myCtr = (CallScript)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl.ascx");
    myCtr.property = "something"; // set public properties
    myCtr.initControl(); // do some database calls
    myCtrPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myCtr);
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="myCtrPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel/>
```

Custom Control C#:

```
public void initControl() 
{
    // do some db calls first and pass it to client side via ASP controls
    // then dynamically produce html elements within the custom control
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "name", "alert(1); documentReady();", true);} 
    // PROBLEM: page says documentReady() is not defined.
}
```

Custom Control HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // PROBLEM: this doesn't get registered to DOM
    function documentReady() {
        // load more controls dynamically         
    }
</script>
<div>
<!-- some html buttons and stuff
</div>
```

Parent html loads the custom control's HTML buttons and other stuff within the update panel into the place holder. Also on every dropdown change, the correct database calls are made within custom control's C#. I also can see my test alert produced from the Custom Control's C#. **However, custom control's script does not get registered to the DOM somehow so I cannot call `documentReady();` after postback.**

Help me SO.

Please.

Thanks.

PS: So far I've tried creating the custom control in a non-dynamic fashion. I've tried creating a js file and putting all the js code of custom control there and calling it within the parent HTML. This sounds promising but I'm trying to achieve to wrap things in a single custom ASP control. I've monkeyed around using `RegisterStartupScript` within parent's C# and few more stuff without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no other way of registering the script within the ascx to the page than using `RegisterStartupScript` which ditches maintainability or editing your script to be a javascript library and giving up on the ascx. I solved my problem by **getting rid of my UpdatePanel** and sacrificed on the page performance. My custom control gets loaded during the non-postback load and I got rid of the logic within the dropdown change.

Time to adopt AngularJS I guess...

Cheers SO!