# Geting javascript error when downloding a xls file from server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have situation where I'm opening a modal window using javascript i.e `"download.aspx"`, On this aspx file I have a textbox to input ID and based upon this ID I query server and then download and XLS file from a location.

I'm using Ajax on my parent window .

Every thing goes fine , but when I do `Response.Transmit("~/filename.xls");`

Also I'm registring the Javascipt with `"RegisterClientScriptBlock()"  or RegisterStartupScript()`

I'm getting follwing error

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:` The script tag registered for type `'ASP.downloadxls_aspx'` and key `'TicketNotExist'` has invalid characters outside of the script tags: `alert('Recipient does not exist:')`. Only properly formatted script tags can be registered.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full line of code that calls `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do a Response.Redirect("~/filename.xls") ?

Comment: When I keep the button control inside the update panel then I recieve this error, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."   but If move the button outside the update panel,

Answer (score 0):

Call [`RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) passing `true` as the final parameter, indicating that you are passing script without script tags and you want the ScriptManager to add them for you.  Eg:

```
scriptMgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "TicketNotExist",
    "alert('Recipient does not exist:');", true);
```

Comment: yes but why this doesn't work with ajax, I have a button which is in update panel, on click of this button I'm registring  this javascript

Comment: @Sandeep - it seems like it should work just fine with AJAX.  See this post: [RegisterClientScriptBlock within AJAX method call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297081/registerclientscriptblock-within-ajax-method-call/297291#297291).  Note that he is using `true` in his call.